# Two arm Clinical Trial hypothesis

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, survival, mean, clinical-trials

I am having a clinical trial that is devised in such a way that the treatment is considered effective by physicians, if its "restricted mean survival time" is atleast 5 units more than placebo.

So in such case, if we formulate a superiority trail hypothesis as in,

H0:mu1=mu2 vs H1:mu1>mu2,

and we get a statistically significant difference (betweem treatement and placebo mean times) of say of 2units, should we then conclude that the mean difference is statistically significant but not clinically (as its not atleast 5 units) ?

Please guide me if I am thinking in the correct direction"

Comment: This is clearly just a reposting of https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/567151/clinical-trial-study-hypothesis?noredirect=1#comment1044928_567151 with some small changes. When you need to make small changes to a post, you should do an edit instead. This question still has issues but the prior post was a better forum to help you address those issues.

Comment: @AdamO Okay sir sorry. Would keep that in mind.